Entering a tmux shell renders escape characters
Setting the shell in tmux with set -g default-shell /usr/bin/bash resolves the issue, it seems that nix's default bash shell is not built with readline support as per @Stéphane Chazelas answer.

I haven't had this issue with tmux before, but when I enter into a tmux shell, it doesn't render the \[ as [, but as \[.
So the default Manjaro Bash setup no longer is displayed as:
[twig@twig-pc learnzig]$

but is displayed as:
\[\][twig@twig-pc\[\] learnzig\[\]]$\[\]

Is this some setting in tmux or do I need to get rid of the fancy .bashrc stuff?
Other things like cursor navigation don't work either: you can't go back or move through previous commands.
Extra information:
$ realpath "/proc/$$/exe"
/nix/store/717iy55ncqs0wmhdkwc5fg2vci5wbmq8-bash-5.2p32/bin/bash

$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
5.2.32(1)-release

$ typeset -p SHELL PS1
declare -x SHELL="/nix/store/717iy55ncqs0wmhdkwc5fg2vci5wbmq8-bash-5.2p32/bin/bash"
declare -- PS1="\\[\\033[01;32m\\][\\u@\\h\\[\\033[01;37m\\] \\W\\[\\033[01;32m\\]]\\\$\\[\\033[00m\\] "

$ echo "$TERM";stty -a

tmux-256color
speed 38400 baud; rows 46; columns 106; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>;
start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel
iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho
-extproc

$ type bind
# inside
bash: type: bind: not found

# outside
bind is a shell builtin



Were the extra commands run before starting tmux or from inside it?

@ChrisDavies run from inside tmux - typeset PS1 doesnt change, realpath & version are slightly different, but all are still bash outside of tmux

echo "$TERM;stty -a in each of the two environments.  Please edit your Question to add information. Do not reply via Add Comment.

Same after you run env -i "$(command -v bash)" --norc and enter that declare -- PS1="\\[\\033[01;32m\\][\\u@\\h\\[\\033[01;37m\\] \\W\\[\\033[01;32m\\]]\\\$\\[\\033[00m\\] " there?

Looking at the source, those \[, \] are not handled (and so left asis) if bash is built without readline support. Like with configure --disable-readline at build time. Does type bind report an error?

@StéphaneChazelas env & declare changed nothing, type bind not found inside tmux

Given that the other escapes (\u, \h, \033...) are expanded, the only explanation I can think of for those \[/\] to be left as-is (as opposed to be treated as hints for readline that what's between has no width as they usually do) is that your bash was built without readline (the line editor) support.
As seen in the code, \[ and \] handling is not built in if readline is not enabled.
I'd also expect the bind command to be unavailable then, set -o emacs or set -o vi to report an error and line editing (other than the crude one by the tty line discipline) to be unavailable.

Thanks! Seems like bash coming from nixpkgs doesn't have readline built in, which is really weird, since I never experienced this issue on my nixos system, only happend on manjaro with nix as the package manager :/

@Twiggeh, maybe that's a stripped down (leaner and faster to start) build intended for scripting and not interactive use and there's a separate build for interactive use or a better interactive shell such as zsh or fish somewhere else. I'm familiar with neither Manjaro nor nix, so can't really comment further.

Related: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/59209 https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/4260 which mention a "bashinteractive" thing separate from "bash" and the bash packaging code.

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d063c1dd113c91ab27959ba540c0d9753409edf3/pkgs/shells/bash/5.nix#L74 is where readline is disabled.
